# XML to json and vice versa spring boot application which internally calls restful service

Tags: spring-boot

Is there any sample spring boot application to accepts soap request and respond in XML only but internally converts xml to json and json to xml?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an object (POJO), you could use JAXB marshaller/unmarshaller for XML (possibly sticking the result into a SOAP-request or -client) while using jersey/jackson for REST-/JSON-related POJO-serialization. I need more details on what you want to accomplish to be more specific and possibly provide a sample project.

Edit: I doubt there's a need to communicate via JSON internally. However: if you are referring to communication between services - sure. Just go the regular way for this and add XML-related endpoint definitions as needed.